# Powershell - A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name

Tags: powershell

Something small I'm missing obviously, but I've followed several PS tutorials and I'm still getting the error.

I have a small PS script that I want to pass an argument to, this is to be eventually used in an Azure DevOps pipeline, but I can't even get this to work locally.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    $EnvironmentName
)

$env = $EnvironmentName

Write-Host "$env"
```

Invoked with: `ps HealthCheck.ps1 -EnvironmentName DEV`

I keep getting the error

```
Get-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EnvironmentName'.
At line:1 char:20
+ ps HealthCheck.ps1 -EnvironmentName DEV
```

Comment: `ps` is an alias for `Get-Process`, and `Get-Process` doesn't have an `-EnvironmentName` parameter (hence the error). Did you name the script "ps HealthCheck.ps1"? If so, use `& '.\ps HealthCheck.ps1'` to invoke it

Comment: and beter change de name $env =  some different name $eenv =  $env = is a fixed value that you cannot use . for instance $env:appdata $env:username...